# SAS: Starting Problem

Tags: sas

Here's the error I receive when trying to start my SAS server.

> Windows could not start the SAS
>   [EMTM-Lev1] Analytics Platform Server
>   service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 1068: The dependency service or
>   group failed to start.

The same goes to the other 3 services which SAS requires them to start to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed that it has expired since December 30th. But the weird thing was it worked last week. Maybe it was the grace period.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the service, look at its properties, and look at the dependencies. What are they? Are they started?

What's changed since it 'used to work'?

Comment: Hi an update here, I have uninstalled and trying to install again now. It used to work for months even until I fully developed an App in my server using port 80. A few days later it stopped starting.

Answer (score 1):

Can you start the services manually or do they exit with an error?

In the past we had problems with the metadata server taking too long to start. That resulted in an error for that service. Depended services were not able to start.

Otherwise you'll have to look at the different log files from the SAS services failing to start